# Pm2 application version not available

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have an Express server whose `package.json` contains `bin` section to create a link to run the app.

I want to run the server using `pm2` and I generated the ecosystem file as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: 'myServer',
    script: 'myserver',
    max_memory_restart: '500M',
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: 'development',
      USER_CONFIG_FILE: '/etc/myserver/myserver-config.json'
    },
    env_production: {
      NODE_ENV: 'production'
    },
    disable_logs: true
  }]
};
```

The ecosystem file is in the home folder of my user (because it will contain all apps) and when I run `pm2 start` the server correctly starts up, but the `version` column of the app table says N/A.

I also tried to add to ecosystem file the `cwd` field set to the directory where the server is installed.

`pm2` shows app version correctly only if I run `pm2 start main.js` from inside the server installation folder.

Is there any way to tell `pm2` how to extract app version when launched from arbitrary folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround avoiding the use of the link created through `bin` section. I used ecosystem field `cwd` to point folder containing `package.json` and set `script` with the name of main main script.

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: 'myServer',
    cwd: '/path/to/app/',
    script: 'index.js',
    max_memory_restart: '500M',
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: 'development',
      USER_CONFIG_FILE: '/etc/myserver/myserver-config.json'
    },
    env_production: {
      NODE_ENV: 'production'
    },
    disable_logs: true
  }]
```

};